# IF+MID multi-functioning Office 2013

Tags: excel-formula

I am in need of a formula that will effectively eliminate the need for a look up sheet. I currently am using the formula below to decipher a serial number production date. The serial number is alpha numeric. W0E9 is the beginning and the only part of the number I care about. The E is the month and the 09 is the year. With the look up table and formula below I am able to change this to May2009. However, I am curious if there is a formula that I can use which wouldn't require the look up table for the month and still give me the same outcome.

Current formula with look up table

```
=LOOKUP(MID(A2,3,1),'Look Up'!A$2:B$13,'Look Up'!B$2:B$13)&(200+MID(A2,2,1)&MID(A2,4,1))
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have attempted to create couple different string that I have made below and they simply wont prove an actual answer at all. Typically getting hung around the "C".

```
=IF(MID(3,2,1)=A, Jan&IF(MID(3,2,1)=B, Feb&IF(MID(3,2,1)=C, March....etc.
=IF(MID(3,2,1)=A, "Jan",IF(MID(3,2,1)=B, "Feb".....etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=IF(MID(I5,3,1)="A","Jan",IF(MID(I5,3,1)="B","Feb",IF(MID(I5,3,1)="C","Mar",IF(MID(I5,3,1)="D","Apr",IF(MID(I5,3,1)="E","May",)))))
```

But only done up to E or May...
Note I5 was the cell with the W0E9 text in it.
Did not see why you had the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant the formatting to be "WE09", and based on that this should work(also working with the serial number in cell A1):

```
=CHOOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT(MID(A1,2,1)&1)),"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec")&IF(MID(A1,3,2)>RIGHT(YEAR(TODAY()),2),1900+MID(A1,3,2),2000+MID(A1,3,2))
```

This will work for years before 2000 by checking against today's date. If you don't want to use the TODAY() function, you can switch the 'YEAR(TODAY())' with a reference to the current year, either a hard value or a reference to another cell where you have the current year.